# If I'm running my App Engine app on localhost, will I not see a value for X-AppEngine-Country?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, geolocation, ip-address, localhost

According to the [Release Notes](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes):

> All user request have an
>   X-AppEngine-Country header which
>   contains the ISO-3166-1 alpha-2
>   country code for the user, based on
>   the IP address of the client request.

My app is running on localhost with the 1.5.1 Java release which contains the `X-AppEngine-Country` header but I don't seem to be receiving any value for this header in my requests.

Do I have to deploy the app to a production instance to test this feature?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Geolocation is provided by an internal Google service, which isn't available in the development environment.

Comment: I'm using ngrok but still having no value for the country.